# Image in a quote in a bullet list

Tags: support, bug, markdown, images, blockquote

How do I correctly add an image in a quote in a bullet list in Markdown?

I tried this:

```
* Bla
  > ![enter image description here][1]
```

But when the image is too wide, it doesn't scale properly:

[image]

As you can see, the quote ends before the image does.

I first noticed this on Electrical Engineering and then verified here and on StackOverflow.
There's no problem in the android app.

Not sure if this should be [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [support](/questions/tagged/support).

---

As gnat suggested in the comments, I tried the [kbd trick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195/839601). Unfortunately, this doesn't help (neither putting the kbd in the quote in the list, nor putting the kbd directly in the list) - the result is similar to without kbd.

Comment: have you tried [kbd trick](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195/839601 "explained here") instead of quote?

Comment: @gnat now I did - this doesn't help (whether I put kbd in quote or just directly in the list), it's still too wide. Thanks though :)

Comment: consider [edit]ing to clarify that kbd trick doesn't help either

Comment: Images are never scaled down; why would a blockquote be any different?

Comment: @MartijnPieters maybe I'm mistaken in my understanding of 'scaling down', I'm not a native speaker. What I mean, is that normally an image that is too wide to be shown in full-size, takes on the highest width possible, such that it doesn't 'get outside the answer'. In this case however, it's too wide: it 'gets outside the quote'.

Comment: @CamilStaps: right, the CSS sets a maximum width for images in the body. Extending that to blockquotes (which push content to the right) is going to be tricky because you can nest those blockquotes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm wondering if setting max-width to 100% would give problems in other cases. It works with this case, and with images directly in the body.